# CSS selector :active not working on child element click in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="ctr__Wrapper" class="wrapper">
    <div id="ctr" class="control clickable">
        <img src="logo.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS for this:

```
.control
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #666;
    padding: 20px;
}

.control:active
{
    background-color: #bbb;
}
```

When I click on the element "ctr", I see the background color changing, but when I click on the image itself, it doesn't. This works fine in Firefox, but not in IE8. Is there something I can do to solve this in CSS.

The working example can be seen here:
http://jsfiddle.net/miljenko/DNMPd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a background image instead of a real image.

html:

```
<div id="ctr__Wrapper" class="wrapper">
    <div id="ctr" class="control clickable">
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.control
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #666;
    height: 40+height-of-logopx;
    background-image:url(logo.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:20px 20px;
}

.control:active
{
    background-color: #bbb;
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of this, but the specific nature of the project requires this structure. +1 anyway, this would solve the problem if I could apply it...

Comment: In lack of a better answer, I'll accept this. I guess there isn't a way to do this in CSS while keeping the structure.

Comment: I guess (but i have no time to test it now), you could use the old structure when using a invisible (transparent) Image, with z-index:0 and z-index:veryhigh for the div around it. Also you could use a 1x1 Pixel sized invisible image.

Answer (score 0):

because < ie9 don't support :active on anything other than anchor elements. here's your fiddle, that should work in ie8 http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/DNMPd/12/

Comment: It doesn't work in IE8, it has the same behavior as the original one. Background changes on div-click, but not on img-click.

Comment: my bad man, didn't add href attribute. i updated it here: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/DNMPd/13/

Comment: Did you try clicking on the image, and not the background div/a?

Comment: The first statement is patently wrong, `:active` started working on non-anchor elements in IE8. The bug here is something entirely different...

Comment: we're both wrong; ie8 has a bug with negative z-indexed elements when used in conjunction with :active

Comment: @albert, do you mind expanding on your comment? I'm not sure how `z-index` is related here.

Comment: "In Internet Explorer version 8 the manipulation of elements with negative z-index is buggy when used in conjunction with :hover or :active rule" src: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-active also related: http://jhop.me/ie8-bugs

Comment: OK, thanks for the link. James Hopkins' bug list doesn't mention this bug (not even in the Wayback Machine), and anyways I don't see z-index in an examples here. There's [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753215/clicking-a-child-doesnt-trigger-the-parents-active-state-in-ie) still open; I'm watching to see if other answers show up.